# How To Loop Video Between Two TImes

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I know a video can be started at a particular time but how can i loop the video between two times using YouTube JavaScript API.

I searched Google and YouTube API but i can't find the solution.

For eg. i want to loop video between 5 sec and 10 sec
i know for i-frame it can be done by
http://www.youtube.com/embed/Nc9xq-TVyHI?start=05&end=10

DO you know any method to do this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*The API does not provide any method to do this.* The most simple way that I can think of to perform what you are looking to do is to put the YouTube video into an iframe on a site and have javascript reload the iframe after a given amount of time. Of course you must start a timer when the page loads in order to do this. You can reload the iframe using the following code:

```
document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

The main issue with do this is that there is no easy way to tell when the video has buffered, so the code may not always restart the video at the proper time.

If you do go this route, here is documentation on how to use a timer in javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp